# MVC - get button id on form post

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with multiple buttons. On post, I would like to get the id of the button that was actually pressed.

So for instance if button #2 is pressed, I need to be able to access the id for this button and then delete itemid 2:

```
<button name="button" value="DeletePollAnswer" id="Delete1">Delete</button>
<button name="button" value="DeletePollAnswer" id="Delete2">Delete</button>
```

Is this possible? How would you do that in the controler?

Thanks

Comment: You should check out this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442704/how-do-you-handle-multiple-submit-buttons-in-asp-net-mvc-framework/442762#442762

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are going around this the wrong way, generally when forms are submitted it is in key value pairs, with the key being the element `name` attribute and the value being the element `value` attribute. If you need to differentiate I would do it there.

IE:

```
<button name="Delete1" value="DeletePollAnswer" id="Delete1">Delete</button>
<button name="Delete2" value="DeletePollAnswer" id="Delete2">Delete</button>
```

Also with MVC it is likely you might want links that would want to call a specific action or pass data to a specific action in which case the an anchor with a an action link should be invoking the specific action directly.

IE:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Delete Poll Answer", "SomeDeleteAction", "SomePollController", new { pollID = somePollIDValue }, null); %>
```

Of course in that example all the names are completely gibberish, you would want to replace with your controller/action/params etc.

Answer (score 0):

**View:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function SubmitForm(id)
    {
        document.forms[0].action = 'ActionName/' + id;
        document.forms[0].submit();
    }
</script>
<% Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post); %>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="Ok" onclick="javascript:SubmitForm('btn1')" />
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="javascript:SubmitForm('btn2')" />
<% Html.EndForm(); %>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult ActionName(string id)
{
    if (id == "btn1")
        //Exec(xxx);
    else
        //Exec(yyy);
        return View();
}
```